# DataTables make the pagination and display counts appear at the top

Tags: datatables

When using the [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net)

How would I make the paging and the Showing 1 to 8 of 8 entries appear at the top rather than the bottom?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every datatable control is named with unique `id`'s after the scheme `<tableid>_info`, `<tableid>_pagination` and so on. So they are easy to locate and then move around.

If you have a table `#example` you would perhaps initialize the dataTable like this :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
})
```

and after that, move the controls to above the table like this :

```js
$("#example_info").detach().prependTo('#example_wrapper');
$("#example_paginate").detach().prependTo('#example_wrapper');
```

And for avoiding that the two controls are misaligned vertically :

```css
#example_info {
    clear: none;
}
```

see working fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/C6CWE/**

Comment: Amazing; thank you very much. I wasn't aware of the detach method! That's awesome!

Answer (score 3):

just add dom property in option as lfrtip to lfript

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
               dom:"lfrtip"
});,
```

this will move the info and pagination on the top of the table

see the documentation https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but I found the below code more suitable and can be customized based on our needs using the dataTable dom options

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
} );
```

Reference Link - https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom